# how can i get similar post from database

Tags: php, sql

i have a news script and i wanna get similar news from database

Any help

i have this

```
table => news
fields => id, title, news
```

and i used this code

```
    $select = $mysqli->query("SELECT * from news  WHERE title LIKE '%$title%' LIMIT 4 ");
$num = $select->num_rows;
while ($rows = $select->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)){  
$id_news       = $rows ['id'];
$title_news       = $rows ['title'];
$news_news       = $rows ['news'];

echo '<a href="'.$id_news.'">'.$title_news.'</a>';

}
```

but i think this for search and  i didn't get the desired results

any another code to get similar news from database

thanks

Comment: Please define what you mean by similar. Do you mean with the same words? If so, how many? Do they need to be the exact same words (e.g. plural to plural, etc.)? Do you mean with the same subject? Please be as clear as you can when defining what similarity means for you.

Comment: @Technoh yes i mean same subject

Answer (score 1):

This is hard to answer because we don't know what "similar" means to you, but you might want to look at [MySQL Full-Text Search Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html)

Comment: If you mean really **the same** then you don't even need the `%` and you already have the correct query. If you actually don't mean **the same** please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no quick, clear cut way to do this. You are asking for full-text keyword or semantic search and that is a highly advanced subject. There are complete search servers designed wholly for that purpose (Sphinx - http://sphinxsearch.com/ - is the first one that comes to mind).

In my opinion you have two options:

1. Switch to a search server, like Sphinx, and use that technology. This is outside the scope of this question.
2. Transform your database schema, which I'll explain below.

For option #2, you could, for example, add a `keywords` table and insert keywords for each article. Then, when searching, you could do a lookup for any article, using its keywords, and find out articles with the same keywords.